# AADSTS9002326: Error on MSAL Auth code flow

Tags: reactjs, azure-ad-msal, msal-react

I recently migrated my react application from MSAL 1.0(implicit) to MSAL 2.0(Auth code flow). I moved my redirect urls to Single Page Application in azure app registration. But I still get this error. Any guess ? #help #MSAL

AADSTS9002326: Cross-origin token redemption is permitted only for the 'Single-Page Application' client-type

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is the redirect URI of type "spa"? This is required for MSAL.js v2 to work cross-origin.[Solution to your problem](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/2338#issuecomment-698515769)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).